# converting cell array that contains vectors into a table in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to convert a cell array (1671 X 2) into a table.

Cell array description:

> First column contains a file path - a string ('home\eladk\balanced_data\1_1.tif'), second column contains a vector ([401,85,82,86]).

I tried using `cell2table` function and got each member of a vector in a separate column (4 colunms total) **insted of the whole vector in one column**

How can I do a conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the second column of the table `T` with the second column of the cell array `C`. Use smooth parentheses `()` to refer to sets of cells, as explained in the Mathworks documentation page: [Access Data in a Cell Array](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html)

Example:

```
% Create a sample cell array.
C = {'ABC', [1 2 3];
     'DEF', [4 5 6]}
C = 
    'ABC'    [1x3 double]
    'DEF'    [1x3 double]

% Convert cell array to table.
T = cell2table(C)
T = 
     C1          C2     
    _____    ___________
    'ABC'    1    2    3
    'DEF'    4    5    6

% Replace the second column of the table with a cell array of vectors.
T.C2 = C(:, 2)
T = 
     C1           C2     
    _____    ____________
    'ABC'    [1x3 double]
    'DEF'    [1x3 double]
```